# How can I filter the custom ListView with edit Text?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have tried for hours looking through examples and other people's code but I still don't quite understand it.

I have my own method, which half works.

```
public class List_of_recipes extends ActionBarActivity {
    //original
    public List<List_view_class> list_view_class;
    ArrayAdapter<List_view_class> adapter;

    // not the original 
    public List<List_view_class> another_list_class;
    public ListView list;
    public EditText edit_text;
    //ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_recipes);

        //  actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#A02727")));

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        list_view_class = new ArrayList<List_view_class>();
        another_list_class = new ArrayList<List_view_class>();
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(list_view_class);

        list_view_class.add(new List_view_class(R.drawable.chicken, "Chicken salad", "15 min", "Easy", "4 serves"));
        list_view_class.add(new List_view_class(R.drawable.mexican, "Mexican egg soup", "20 min", "Easy", "2 serves"));
        list_view_class.add(new List_view_class(R.drawable.oyster, "Oysters with pancetta", "10 min", "Super Easy", "2 serves"));
        //list_view_class.add(new List_view_class(R.drawable.wild_mushroom,"Wild mushroom crostini","5 min", "Easy","6 serves"));

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View viewclicked, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(List_of_recipes.this, Chicken_salad.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(List_of_recipes.this, Mexican_egg.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(List_of_recipes.this, Oyster.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String searchString = edit_text.getText().toString();
                another_list_class.clear();
                int textLength = edit_text.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < list_view_class.size(); i++) {
                    String name = list_view_class.get(i).gettitle().toString();

                    if (textLength <= name.length()) {
                        if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(name.substring(0, textLength))) {
                            another_list_class.add(list_view_class.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter = new MyListAdapter(another_list_class);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List_view_class> {
        public MyListAdapter(List<List_view_class> object_class) {
            super(List_of_recipes.this, R.layout.activity_list_class_view, object_class);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = convertView;

            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) List_of_recipes.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_class_view, null, true);
            }

            List_view_class listclass = list_view_class.get(position);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(listclass.getrecipe_icon());
            TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            date.setText(listclass.gettitle());
            TextView cook = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cooktime);
            cook.setText(listclass.getcook_time());
            TextView diff = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.difficultylvl);
            diff.setText(listclass.getdifficulty());
            TextView serve = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.serving);
            serve.setText(listclass.getmakes());

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

It gives no errors, but all I am getting is the first list view item no matter what I type.

I am not sure what else to add or what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: What do you mean "filter" with edittexts? Do you want to built your own Listview item?

Comment: try moving notifyDataSetChanged(), after you set the new adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
there is no need to create another adapter again and again on edit text change.you can refresh list view by just calling notifyDataSetChanged  on adapter.

String searchString = s.toString();
     another_list_class.clear();
     for(int i =0; i< list_view_class.size(); i++){
             String name = list_view_class.get(i).gettitle().toString();
             if(name.contains(searchString))
             {
                   another_list_class.add(list_view_class.get(i));
             }
     }
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    equalsIgnoreCase returns true if and only if two strings are exactly equal(Ignoring case sensitive);

You can also use startWith in place of contains
One more thing set your adpater with another_list_class arraylist initially.
because in this example we are changing search result in another_list_class .
```

It is better to put code in afterTextChanged.

Comment: incase notifyDatasetchanged() doesnt work  then use notifyDatasetInvalidate(); as it will force the adapter to change.

Comment: Thank you for your time Navin, I understand up till the part when you said "set your adpater with another_list_class arraylist initially.
because in this example we are changing search result in another_list_class ." Could you please elaborate on this part? Not sure what you mean

Comment: If we set Adapter with arraylist1 and we are changing arraylist2.than there is not any change occure in arraylist1.thus on notifying adapter for refresh,  It will populate listview with arraylist1 because it has reference of that one.So no changes occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move code to `afterTextChanged`

int textLength=edit_text.getText()!=null?edit_text.getText().toString().length():0;

```
     for(int i =0; i< list_view_class.size(); i++)
     { 
         String name = list_view_class.get(i).gettitle().toString();

         if(textLength <= name.length()){

             if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(name.substring(0,textLength)))
             { 
                 another_list_class.add(list_view_class.get(i));
             } 

         } 
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, I did move the code to afterTextChanged, but still gives me same result. :(